# Is "Proof-of-work" a subset of "Byzantine fault tolerance (BFT)"?

Tags: proof-of-work, consensus

Can we say that `Proof-of-work` is a type of `Byzantine fault tolerance (BFT)` ? In other words, is **PoW** a subset of **BFT** ? Or they are two different categories?

**Please note** that there is a similar question here ([BFT VS Bitcoin PoW VS PBFT](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75923/41513)) but without any answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BFT VS Bitcoin PoW VS PBFT](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/75923/bft-vs-bitcoin-pow-vs-pbft)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between PoW and BFT](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/88906/difference-between-pow-and-bft)

Answer (score 3):

> Can we say that Proof-of-work is a type of Byzantine fault tolerance
>   (BFT) ? In other words, is PoW a subset of BFT?

Yeah I think you can say that.

Proof-of-work is a proposed (and pretty well tested at this point) solution to the [Byzantine Generals Problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20170205142845/http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/byz.pdf), and therefore achieves [Byzantine Fault Tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance). The Byzantine faults that it solves includes the classic [double spend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-spending).

The Byzantine Generals Problem is an illustration of the difficulty in arriving at consensus in a distributed network.